# How to use DCT to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\bf{R}} (1+\frac{x^2}{n})^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} dx = \int_{\bf{R}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx $?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Use the dominated convergence theorem to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+\frac{x^2}{n})^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} \mathrm dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \mathrm dx  $$

You may use that for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $(1+\frac{a}{n})^n \to e^a$ as $n \to \infty$.

In the the question above, I think that my first step would be to try and eliminate the $n$ terms in $f_n(x)$ and find a bounding function $g(x)$.

Then manipulate $f_n(x)$ such that I can use the converging property given.

I just don't know where to start with the bounding function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a \ge 0$ and $t >\max(a,2)$, the binomial theorem shows that
$(1+{a \over t})^t \ge 1+ a$.

Now note that
$(1 + { x^2 \over n} ) ^ {- { n+1  \over 2 } } = {1 \over \left(1 + { {x^2 \over 2}  \over {n \over 2}} \right)^ { n \over 2} (1 + { x^2 \over n} )^{1 \over 2} } $.

We have $(1 + { x^2 \over n} )^{1 \over 2} \ge 1 $, and
$\left(1 + { {x^2 \over 2}  \over {n \over 2}} \right)^ { n \over 2} \ge 1+ {x^2 \over 2}$, hence
$(1 + { x^2 \over n} ) ^ {- { n+1  \over 2 } } \le {1 \over 1+ {x^2 \over 2}}$. The latter term is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Now note that $(1 + { x^2 \over n} )^{1 \over 2} \to 1$, and
$\left(1 + { {x^2 \over 2}  \over {n \over 2}} \right)^ { n \over 2} \to e^{{x^2 \over 2}}$.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little sloppy above - let me fix it...

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I had got the the point of splitting the exponential but didn't think of applying the binomial theorem the way that you did.

Comment: Glad to help. My first shot at a solution was flawed.

Answer (score 0):

A brutal (but efficient) way to show that the $f_n$s are bounded by an integrable function is to use the trivial inequality:

$$f_n(x)=\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}\leq e^{-x^2/2}+f_1(x)=e^{-x^2/2}+\frac{1}{x^2+1}.$$